# Influxdb2 flux's today() function using wrong timezone

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

This is my query:

```
from(bucket: "power_monitor")
|> range(start: today())
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
|> keep(columns: ["_measurement", "_value", "_time"])
|> increase()
|> last()
```

It tracks the amount of energy used since the start of the day, except I think the timezone is wrong... it was working perfectly until ~8pm when all values were reset to zero.

Can I fix this in the query by adding a time offset? or set my timezone?
I think I'd like the values to reset around 2am.

I got this from influx docs and added it to the query, but it doesn't seem to help (still all zeros):

```
import "timezone"
timezone.fixed(offset: -4h)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `location` **option**, ie.

```js
import "timezone"

option location = timezone.fixed(offset: -4h) 

from(bucket: "power_monitor")
  ...
```

Or use `location` parameter of `aggregateWindow` function, ie.

```js
from(bucket: "power_monitor")
  ...
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, createEmpty: false, location: timezone.fixed(offset: -4h))
```

Comment: setting timezone with fixed offset did not work, but setting via named location did! ie: `option location = timezone.location(name: "America/Toronto")`.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a workaround, but accepted answer will be one which uses timezones and not experimental function.

workaround:

```
import "experimental"
starttime = () => experimental.addDuration(d: -6h, to: today())

from(bucket: "power_monitor")
  |> range(start: starttime())
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> keep(columns: ["_measurement", "_value", "_time"])
  |> increase()
  |> last()
```

Comment: Shifting the starttime a couple of hours is never a good idea to solve a timezone issue.